# Extending a linearly independent subset into a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that $S = \{(1,2,1,0,0)\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, where

$V= \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5):x_1 - 2x_2 +3x_3 - x_4 + 2x_5 = 0\}$.

I now have to extend $S$ into a basis for $V$. Is there a better way rather than trying different sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find any basis $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ for $V$, and $(1,2,1,0,0) = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 + a_4 b_4$ where $a_1,\ldots,a_4$ are scalars with $a_1 \neq 0$, then $\{(1,2,1,0,0),b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ is also a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct step by step a basis $\{ b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4 \}$ for V.

Let $b_1$ be your vector (1,2,1,0,0).

To begin with, choose any  vector that is not a multiple of $b_1$. For example< $b_2 = (0,0,0,2,1)$.

Now you have to choose a vector $b_3$ such that:

$$ b_3 \in V \mbox{ BUT } b_3 \not \in [b_1,b_2] $$ where $[b_1,b_2]$ is the space generated by $b_1$ and $b_2$.

As $[b_1,b_2] = \{ (a,2a,a,2b,b) / a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$, then:

for example, let $b_3$ be (0,1,0,0,1).

To end, you should only choose a $b_4$ such that:

$$ b_4 \in V \mbox{ BUT } b_4 \not \in [b_1,b_2,b_3] $$